# Pytorch Install

Tags: pytorch, anaconda3, windows-11, gpytorch

I HAVE A ERROR IN INSTALLING PYTORCH:
PLEASE HELP ME.
CondaHTTPError: HTT P000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64/current_repodata.json
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https//conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way

The possible reason for HTTP error could be an unstable network connection or a corporate firewall.

If it was an unstable network connection, **as mentioned in the Error message, retry the installation steps that failed.**

If you are behind a corporate firewall, you might need additional steps to add your proxy server to the `.condarc` file on your machine.

- Since you are on Windows, you could open the Anaconda prompt and run `conda info` to figure out where the `.condarc` file is located.
- Find the proxy by running `echo "$http_proxy"` in your prompt. Copy the proxy.
- Open the `.condarc` file and paste the proxy under `proxy_servers` section

For more details see: [Anaconda Docs: Configure conda for use behind a proxy server (proxy_servers)](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#configure-conda-for-use-behind-a-proxy-server-proxy-servers)

Comment: hello. thanks for your help.
I do all of steps : by running echo "$http_proxy" in my prompt but I don't have proxy.


 and .condarc file content:
channels:
  - "'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/'"
  - "'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/"
  - defaults
ssl_verify: false
show_channel_urls: true

Comment: Before you go and edit `.condarc` and add proxy details, did you retry the step without any changes? I would do that first because if it was just a network instability, it would work without any config changes.